# How can I get flake8 to catch this error?

Tags: python-3.x, pylint, flake8

On this test program:

```
def func():
    return 42

func(1, 2, 3)
```

`pylint -E` it says:

```
E1121: Too many positional arguments for function call (too-many-function-args)
```

But `flake8` says no errors or warnings. This is a huge obvious error why does `flake8` not catch this? Do I need certain flags?

pylint 2.5.2

flake8 3.8.2 (pyflakes 2.2.0)

Python 3.8.1 on Mac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyFlakes (that flake8 uses) does not do that type of checking.

I filed [an issue](https://github.com/PyCQA/pyflakes/issues/560) with the PyFlakes project and received a quick response: "pyflakes works entirely statically and does not do any type analysis (it does not follow imports or function calls, etc.). this design is chosen to keep pyflakes fast and simple ... If you're looking for type analysis, you're best to use a type checker such as mypy or a tool like pylint."

I asked is the number of arguments really "type analysis" and they said "in python, the shape of a callable is its type (number of parameters, kwonly, posonly, defaulted, collecting, etc.)"